# requests and bs4 cannot read the whole html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get all the href in the list in this website:https://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246.
The website is very simple and clean. After reviewing the source, I found nothing dynamic.

However, if I do

```py
import requests

url = 'https://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246'

r = requests.get(url)

r.text
```

`r.text` only contains around 20000 characters information. More than half of the html is missing.

I tried to copy the whole HTML from "view page source" and directly load to Beautifulsoup:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '' # too long to copy. Here is the link: view-source:https://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Still only around 20000 characters are retained and the top half of the html is missing.

Here is my question:

- Is there any character restrictions with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`?
- If so, how can I remove the limitation?
- If not, why I cannot get the full html?

Thanks a lot!

Rachel

Comment: you want to get all `href` links ?

Comment: Yeah. Trying to get all the link/text within the list.

Comment: what do you mean by `list`? check below answer

Comment: Thanks! Just replied you. The list below is still not a complete list.

Comment: From the comments on the answer, it appears that the issue was simply that VS Code is cutting off the lengthy output. I'm therefore voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced.

Comment: Yeah. That's fine. Didn't realize the issue was the output limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


for item in soup.findAll("a", href=True):
    item = item.get("href")
    if item.startswith("http"):
        print(item)
```

output:

```
https://nihongonosensei.net/
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3547
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3563
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3568
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3600
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3614
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3618
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3622
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3626
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3633
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3695
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3697
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3702
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3707
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3710
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3712
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3714
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3719
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3722
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3726
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3730
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3733
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3735
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5236
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5238
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5240
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5244
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5618
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5620
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5961
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5965
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5967
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5970
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5972
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6772
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7977
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7979
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7983
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7985
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7987
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8869
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8891
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9192
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9197
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9198
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9199
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9219
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9221
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9223
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9249
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9280
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9320
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9322
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9324
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9327
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9329
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9353
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9359
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9360
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13973
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13972
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13974
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11851
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11858
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12202
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12999
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13112
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13364
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13494
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=14887
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=14889
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=14915
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=14918
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17745
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18155
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18159
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18188
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18206
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18204
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18223
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18407
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18460
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18461
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18578
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18611
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18696
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18705
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18707
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18763
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3738
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3745
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3759
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3776
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3778
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3781
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3783
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3785
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3797
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3799
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3801
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3804
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3809
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3824
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3826
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13941
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3833
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=4097
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5058
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5246
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5248
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5251
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5253
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5255
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5616
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5614
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5978
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5982
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5974
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6203
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6205
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11829
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11830
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6209
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6211
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7909
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7970
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7972
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7974
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7990
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7992
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8008
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8010
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8012
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9447
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9452
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9876
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9884
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9890
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9891
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9945
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=14072
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=14073
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=10533
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=10532
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11855
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11521
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18734
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18726
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11862
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11864
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11866
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12025
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12027
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12115
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13076
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13142
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13145
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13453
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13456
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13459
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13479
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13483
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3535
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=14896
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18263
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18324
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18366
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18373
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18381
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18398
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18680
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18682
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18684
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1700
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1708
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1713
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1718
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1735
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1742
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1745
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1748
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1752
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1755
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1758
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1761
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1764
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1767
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1770
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1773
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1777
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1782
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1785
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1788
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1791
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1794
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1797
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1801
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1804
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1807
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1810
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1813
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1816
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1819
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1823
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1828
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1835
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=1838
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12082
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3470
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3477
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3484
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3492
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3553
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3559
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13970
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6331
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6335
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6339
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6341
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6769
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8506
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8857
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9283
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9306
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9308
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9312
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9314
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9422
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9462
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9860
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11635
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12073
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12784
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12795
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12821
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12824
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12830
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12832
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12834
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12987
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12995
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13018
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3761
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13326
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13327
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13340
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13344
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17748
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17758
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17767
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17771
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18162
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18165
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18171
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18202
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18199
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18314
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18312
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18399
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18400
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18585
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18589
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18591
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18301
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18701
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18773
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18775
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18788
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18790
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18792
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18821
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3571
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9936
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3578
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5980
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3609
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3680
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3828
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6345
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6347
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6351
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7905
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7907
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8063
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18470
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18471
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9425
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9426
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9465
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9466
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9872
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=10058
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11304
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11948
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18497
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18499
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18501
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12143
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12789
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12882
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12885
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12886
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13074
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13087
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13092
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13136
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13151
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13371
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18157
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18219
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18221
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18266
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18292
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18293
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18392
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18488
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18489
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18593
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18595
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18612
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18613
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18657
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18659
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18662
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18664
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12827
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=4094
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18732
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18728
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18720
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18722
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18730
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18724
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=4094
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3500
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3526
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3529
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3474
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3585
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3606
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3643
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3650
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3656
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5062
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5941
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5943
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5945
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5947
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5949
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5984
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7024
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7026
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7096
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7098
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7100
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7102
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7104
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7152
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=10116
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3550
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8048
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6349
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8051
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8058
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8061
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8070
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8080
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8082
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=4085
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=4088
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8540
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8542
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8558
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8564
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8665
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8669
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8672
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8675
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8710
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8705
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7981
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8724
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8730
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8733
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8856
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9310
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9352
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5242
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9385
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9386
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9488
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9487
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12075
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18193
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18350
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18351
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18406
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18428
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18447
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18587
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18698
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18695
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18703
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3659
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3673
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3676
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3683
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3686
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18190
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3747
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3749
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3753
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5951
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5953
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5955
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5957
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7068
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7071
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7075
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7121
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3541
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8004
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=6343
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8144
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8143
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8150
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8152
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8161
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8164
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8257
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9482
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8261
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8159
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8272
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8274
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8277
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8279
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9215
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9217
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9859
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=10102
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18631
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18632
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11303
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12781
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12812
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12799
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12802
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12809
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13150
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11946
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13152
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18503
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3582
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17664
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17751
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18264
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18267
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18265
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18303
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18393
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8281
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18614
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18676
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18678
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18816
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18818
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18812
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18809
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18807
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18805
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18803
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18330
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3446
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3662
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5182
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9262
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9264
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3647
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8567
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9343
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8045
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18305
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18307
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18427
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18615
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18713
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18715
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18717
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18736
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3668
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5180
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=4090
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11943
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11950
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11941
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=12816
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18323
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18349
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18784
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18786
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18814
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18405
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=5233
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7154
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7938
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=7943
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8509
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8541
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8886
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=8889
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9440
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=9441
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3639
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3575
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3603
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11627
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11953
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11955
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17914
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18195
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18217
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18348
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18371
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18375
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18377
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18379
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18653
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18655
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13346
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13347
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13348
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13358
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13362
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13373
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13369
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13379
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13385
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13462
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=13466
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=14905
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17576
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17593
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17597
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17600
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17917
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18268
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18363
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=19118
http://nihongonosensei.net/
http://nihongonosensei.net/?cat=7
http://nihongonosensei.net/?cat=3
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246#linkn1
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246#linkn2
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246#linkn3
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246#linkn4n5
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246#linkn0
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=13879
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874
http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=17729
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874#link2019
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874#link30
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874#link29
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874#link28
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874#link27
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874#link26
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874#link25
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874#link24
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=8874#link23
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=4945
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=5094
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=13794
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=13794#link1
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=13794#link2
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=13825
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=13827
http://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=1904
https://thk.kanzae.net/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, if you look at the source HTML, the href starts with "http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3547", but this link is not in the list. This list is still not a complete list. `requests` still only gets part of the html.

link to source: view-source:https://nihongonosensei.net/?page_id=10246

Comment: @Mukerong it's actually shown correctly. [check-printscreen](https://i.ibb.co/DbV6rXG/Capture.png) . which already included in the answer. check output second line !! looks like you are using `Google Chrome`?

Comment: Another interesting fact. I copied your answer, and there are 579 lines. If I ran the same code, my list only had 557. Two possible explanation:

* something wrong with my VSCode preview
* something wrong in my python setting.

Comment: @Mukerong comment section is not for spreading a `codes` you can edit your question, however the `len` is `579`.

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to the posting.

Check my list again. I have 579 length as well! When I did `print` in VSCode, it only show list starting at "3735". It might be a preview issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mukerong it's not a preview issue at all. !! you just need to configure the size of output within `VSCode` !

Comment: @Mukerong Was that the issue?

Comment: @AMC, what do you mean?

Comment: @Mukerong Was the issue that VSCode was cutting off the output when displaying it, and you were only checking it visually?